# Connecting two specific points on a map for linking between HF radio site

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gis

I'm working on a ham radio project and I've run into a bit of a wall. I'm trying to take a map and make a link between the transmitter and the receiver.

Data

```
rx_sign <- c("2E0ILY/KIWI","ND7M","KP4MD","N2HQI","WA2N","WA2ZKD","OE9TAV","2E0PYB","OE9TAV","2E0ILY/KIWI")
rx_lat <- c(52.896,36.229,38.688,43.021,35.813,43.146,47.438,51.771,47.438,52.896)
rx_lon <- c(-2.625,-116.042,-121.292,-76.458,-82.542,-77.625,9.625,0.708,9.625,-2.625)
tx_sign <- c("2E0JCC","AA5GI","AC9YY","AC9YY","AC9YY","AC9YY","DC6EB","DG8GAD","DG8GAD","DK9MS")
tx_lat <- c(51.479,35.479,41.813,41.813,41.813,41.813,49.479,48.438,48.438,50.479)
tx_lon <- c(-2.708,-95.042,-88.042,-88.042,-88.042,-88.042,6.958,9.875,9.875,8.958)

map_data <- data.frame(rx_sign,rx_lat,rx_lon,tx_sign,tx_lat,tx_lon)
```

My goal is to make a map that looks like this. I've connected cities on maps before but for whatever reason having multiple connections has stumped me.
[image: Goal is to make a map that looks like this]

In the past I've make pairs for each city with it's lat/lon then connected them like this. I know that this isn't the right way to do this with the data that I have but it's kind of stumped me and I can't quite get my head around how to fix this.

```
base_world <- map_data("world")

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=base_world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_line(data=map_data, aes(x=rx_lon, y=rx_lat), color="red", size=1) +
  geom_line(data=map_data, aes(x=tx_lon, y=tx_lat), color="green", size=1) +
  geom_point(data=map_data, aes(x=rx_lon, y=rx_lat), colour = "yellow", size=1.5, alpha=I(0.7)) +
  geom_point(data=map_data, aes(x=tx_lon, y=tx_lat), colour = "blue", size=1.5, alpha=I(0.7)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=20), legend.position="none")
```

[image: ggplot2 fail]

Comment: This will be dependent on your data. A ham radio 'CQ' event will have multiple trans/receiv pairs,but useful where to looks might be [draw connecting routes](https://r-graph-gallery.com/how-to-draw-connecting-routes-on-map-with-r-and-great-circles.html), or looking further into R graph [connection maps](https://r-graph-gallery.com/connection-map.html), where, looking at worked examples you may see data and examples that look like your desired.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this, I had looked at this site early on in my search but missed this bit. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll want to pivot your data longer, with an id linking each tx/rx pair. You can then pass this id to the `group` aesthetic in `geom_line()`. (This also gives you a tx vs. rx variable you can map to `color` in `geom_point()`.)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

map_data <- map_data %>%
  mutate(link = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    !link,
    names_to = c("txrx", ".value"),
    names_sep = "_"
  )

p <- ggplot(map_data) +
  geom_polygon(data=base_world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=lon, y=lat, group = link), color="red", size=1) +
  geom_point(data=map_data, aes(x=lon, y=lat, colour = txrx), alpha=0.7) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=20), legend.position="none") + 
  coord_quickmap()
  
p
```

[image]

If you want to crop to just certain regions, you can set limits inside `coord_quickmap()`.

```
p + coord_quickmap(xlim = c(-140, 20), ylim = c(20, NA))
```

[image]